# How to refer to a class from within a constant array of record?

Tags: class, delphi, delphi-xe2, record

I have a class, TiffData that contains abstract methods to load and display data, and a number of ancestor classes like TTiffByte, TTiffAscii, TTiffShort that define those methods.

I also have a constant array or records that lets me look up information about types based on the data type recorded in the IFD.

What I can't figure out, how to store the associated class for each array element.

```
type
    TtiffType = record
      name  : string;
      bytes : word;
      data  : class;   {  ?  }
      desc  : string;
    end;

const
TiffTypes : array[ 1 .. 18 ] of TTiffType =  (

{01} ( name: 'byte';  bytes : 1; data: TTiffByte;     { ? }
       desc: '8-bit unsigned number.'   ),
{02} ( name: 'ascii';  bytes : 1; data: TTiffAscii;   { ? }
       desc: '8 bit byte that contains a 7 bit ASCII code; the last byte must be NULL (binary zero)'   ),
{03} ( name: 'short';  bytes : 2; data: TTiffShort;   { ? }
       desc: '16-bit (2-byte) unsigned integer.'   ),
...
```

What I would like to do is hold a reference to the class in the array:

```
value := TiffTypes[ fldType ].Data.Create;

value.loadFromOffset( offset );
Edit1.Text := value.getShortString;
```

or  hold a constructor in the array:

```
value := TiffTypes[ fldType ].data;

value.loadFromFile( f, offset, count );
InternalRepresentation := TTiffAscii( value.storage );
```

Answer (score 7):

Since your classes have a common base class, `TiffData`, you can use `class of TiffData` in your record, eg:

```
type
  TtiffType = record
    name  : string;
    bytes : word;
    data  : class of TiffData; // <-- here
    desc  : string;
  end;
```

Using `Data.Create` will then work as expected, as long as the constructor for `TiffData` is declared as `virtual` and each derived class overrides it.

Comment: Why does the constructor need to be declared as virtual? Wouldn't it work regardless?

Comment: No. Lets say `Data` points to `TTiffByte`. Calling `Data.Create` **will not** call `TTiffByte.Create` if `TiffData.Create` is not virtual. Virtual constructors are very important when creating objects using metaclasses.

Comment: Understand now why you say that. I almost never put anything in constructors. I use AfterConstruction and BeforeDestruction where possible. The reason I switched a long time ago was exactly because of that reason. At the time I didn't know what the reason for it was just that my constructor was never being called :). +1 for the important info.

Comment: The constructor does not *need* to be virtual. The correct object will be created regardless. You only need it to be virtual if descendants need to override it, which is the same criterion as for making any other method virtual. Constructors aren't special in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a meta class.

```
type
  TTiffDataClass = class of TiffData;
```

You can then use it like this:

```
TTiffType = record
  name  : string;
  bytes : word;
  data  : TTiffDataClass;
  desc  : string;
end;
```

If you have a descendent of the TiffData then you can use that. For example:

```
TTiffByte= class(TiffData)
end;
```

This should work:

```
{01} ( name: 'byte';  bytes : 1; data: TTiffByte;     { ? }
       desc: '8-bit unsigned number.'   ),
```

As Remi said in his answer, be careful of the constructors.

Comment: The OP stated that the base class is named `TiffData` so you should reflect that in your answer instead of making up a new fictitious name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Remi and Graymatter! I used info from both answers to get the following result.  Pretty much anything different gives warnings, errors or run time exceptions.

Define many classes to manage various data types, all ancestors of TTiffData.

```
Type

TTiffData = class(TObject)
    constructor create; virtual;
    procedure LoadFromIFD( var aValue; Count : LongWord  ); virtual; abstract;
end;

TTiffShort = class(TTiffData)
    constructor create; override;
    procedure LoadFromIFD( var aValue; Count : LongWord  ); override;
end;

TTiffAscii = class(TTiffData)
    constructor create; override;
    procedure LoadFromIFD( var aValue; Count : LongWord  ); override;
end;

...
```

Note:  I used 'override' instead of 'virtual' in the children to prevent "Method '*' hides virtual method of base type 'TTiffData'" warnings.

The array looks like this:

```
type
    TTiffDataClass = class of TTiffData;

    TtiffType = record
      name  : string;
      bytes : word;
      data  : TTiffDataClass;
      desc  : string;
    end;

const


   TiffTypes : array[ 1 .. 18 ] of TTiffType =  (
{01} ( name: 'byte';  bytes : 1; data: TTiffShort;
       desc: '8-bit unsigned number.'   ),
{02} ( name: 'ascii';  bytes : 1; data: TTiffAscii;
       desc: '8 bit byte that contains a 7 bit ASCII code; the last byte must be NULL (binary zero)'   ),

...
);
```

Usage:

```
    {  Load }
    Value := TiffTypes[ fldType ].data.Create;

    if Indirect then begin
        Value.LoadFromFile( f, Offset, Count );
        end

    else begin
        ValueLoadFromIFD( Offset, Count );
        end;


    { Display }
    aStringGrid.Cells[ 8, i ] := Value.ShortDisplay;
```

Comment: Ouch. Don't use `override` to "prevent warnings". **Please** learn what it means and use it accordingly.

Comment: You are not preventing warnings, you are preventing your overriding methods from not being called.